# What is encoding characters the URL? Browser or PHP?

Tags: php, html, special-characters, html-entities

Imagine this simple form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Me</legend>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now imagine it is accessed via `form.php?hack=" onsubmit="alert('xss')`

The output when I view source is

```
<form action="/things/?hack=%22%20onsubmit=%22alert(%27xss%27)" method="post">
```

What is encoding this - is it the browser or PHP?

Outside of curiosity, I always echo `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` within `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: You can check this sort of thing by taking the browser out of the equation. I'm somewhat surprised you didn't investigate this yourself by telnetting to the web server.

Comment: @outis I think your assume too much of me. I don't know how to do that. Though I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @alex: fortunately, there's not much too it, given the simplicity of HTTP. Ease of debugging was one of the two main reasons HTTP is a plain-text, rather than binary, protocol. If you want a mini-guide, there are plenty of webpages that show the basics (http://www.google.com/search?q=http+telnet).

Comment: @outis Thanks for the links. I had a quick go before bed but my server kept responding with some HTML I have never seen before. Not sure what that was about (missing the HTTP GET perhaps?) I did `telnet alexanderdickson.com 80` in Windows command prompt.

Comment: @alex: you're missing some headers. "alexanderdickson.com" is a virtual host, so you need a "Host:" header. There may be others.

Comment: @outis Ah yeah... I didn't know that would affect it. I'll have another go tonight. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is done by the browsers, if you are under some PHP framework, some of them also change it. It is similar to what you do using PHP's `urlencode` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `form.php?hack=" onsubmit="alert('xss')` into your address field of your browser, it converts it to `form.php?hack=%22%20onsubmit=%22alert(%27xss%27)` as the `"` and space characters are not allowed in a URI. So they must be encoded. The `'` is allowed in URIs but may also be encoded.

Comment: Will any user agents not do this?

Comment: @alex: Lynx 2.8.6rel.5 appears not to, for one.